# bash: simpler way to get multiple elements of array at once?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Is there a *nix command that formats input (delimited by newlines) so that only a specific max number of elements appear per line? For example:

```
$ yes x | head -10 | command 4
x x x x
x x x x
x x
```

I wrote a quick `bash` script (shown below) that performs this task, but it seems long and probably inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]; then
        echo Usage `basename $0` {rows} {columns}
        exit 1
fi

ROWS=$1
COLS=$2

input=$(yes x | head -${ROWS})
lines=()
i=0
j=0
eol=0

for x in ${input[*]}
do
        lines[$i]="${lines[$i]} $x"
        j=`expr $j + 1`
        eol=0
        if [ $j -ge ${COLS} ]; then
                echo lines[$i] = ${lines[$i]}
                i=`expr $i + 1`
                j=0
                eol=1
        fi
done

if [ ${eol} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo lines[$i] = ${lines[$i]}
fi
```

Comment: `for x in "${input[@]}"`, `((j++))`, `if ((j >= COLS))`, `lines[i]`, `echo "..."`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf '%-10s%-10s%-10s%s\n' $(command | command)
```

`printf` will consume the number of arguments specified in the format string at a time and continue until they're all consumed.

Demonstration:

```
$ printf '%-10s%-10s%-10s%s\n' $(yes x | head -n 10)
x         x         x         x
x         x         x         x
x         x
$ printf '%-10s%-10s%-10s%s\n' $(<speech)
now       is        the       time
for       all       good      men
to        come      to        the
aid       of        their     country
```

Comment: @user46874: Here's how you can build the format string dynamically given that the number of fields is contained in `$n`: `printf -v format '%*s' "$n" ''; format="${format// /%-10s}\n"; printf "$format" $(...)`. The last field will have trailing blanks, but that may not be a problem. If it is, use `$((n - 1))` in the first step and the second step would be `format="${format// /%-10s}%s\n"`

Answer (score 8):

Arrays can be sliced.

```
$ foo=(q w e r t y u)
$ echo "${foo[@]:0:4}"
q w e r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yes x | head -10 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "%%%%%%%" } { split($0,a,"\n"); for (i=1; i<length(a); i+=4) print a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2], a[i+3] }'
```

More readable:

```
yes x | \
head -10 | \
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "%%%%%%%" }
     { split($0,a,"\n"); 
       for (i=1; i<length(a); i+=4) print a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2], a[i+3] }'
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try something like

```
sed 's|\(.{10}\)|\1\n|'
```

I'working on Window machine and have not tried this.My idea is just match everything for N number of times and replace them with matched pattern plus new line character.

P.S Please correct the sed expression for any syntatic fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xargs(1)](http://mdoc.su/-/xargs.1) for this, with the `-n` or `--max-args=` option to limit the number of arguments per command line:

```
$ yes x | head -10 | xargs -n4
x x x x
x x x x
x x
$
```

Obviously, you have to be able to trust the input; for example, xargs famously breaks if the quotes are not matched:

```
$ yes 'x"' | head -10 | xargs -n4
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
$
```